# Weighted directed graph clustering

Tags: graph-theory, clustering

I had a really huge sets of molecules and it's I'd like to compare according to various factors. So I created a similarity measure which was very informative and fitted for comparing different types of molecules. After I introduced comparing between two elements I'd like to go further and try to cluster them, however I've got a problem, my similarity measure is not reflexive, i.e. $dist(A,B)!=dist(B,A)$ (though it satisfies triangle inequality). And I have no problem about it since it represents the problem of my interest perfectly. I generated the distance matrix ( or dissimilarity, my measure is bounded $[0,1]$ so it could be converted to similarity as well ).

I thought that clustering with asymmetric distances isn't common thing, so there is not much algorithms implemented (only ones that I know are OPTICS and DBSCAN, but as I tried they are no good), so I decided maybe I should change this problem to the problem of clustering strongly connected directed graph with weights. Maybe someone is aware of such issue and knows some usable implementation of it?

I found [Tarjan's](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019083900881) article, so maybe someone is familiar with the approach described there and knows possible implementation.

This question is also methodological. Maybe I should check another clustering algorithms, however I don't want to change my measure formula.

Comment: Checking if a distance function satisfies triangle inequality may be useful too...

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention. My distance function satisfies triangle inequality.

Comment: I'm interested in a solution to this. Have you figured out something yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Knowledge Discovery Toolbox (KDT) [here](http://kdt.sourceforge.net/) (a link to a related paper: [A Flexible Open-Source Toolbox for Scalable Complex Graph Analysis](http://cs.ucsb.edu/~yunteng.cs/files/SDM12_KDT.pdf)). Also, take a look at this article: [Preconditioners Based on Strong Subgraphs](http://www.cerfacs.fr/algor/reports/2013/TR_PA_13_25.pdf).